# Bing maps: how to display "See best route based on traffic" after direction request?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

Question regarding Bing Maps v7.
How to display link "See best route based on traffic" after direction request. It seems to set some option in 'DirectionsRequestOptions' but I don't know what exactly. See example here http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#DirectionsModule2  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It displays automatically by Bing Maps, if "best route" is exist for entered address.